# What's the best way to get data back from a jqGrid cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm fairly new to jqGrid and needed to get the data from cell for editing and wanted to avoid accessing the server.

Since a custom formatter is adding extra tags to the data, and simply using `getCell` returns all the tags as well,my first implementation was to strip then off *'manually'*:

```
createColumn: function (val, options) {
    return '<div style="white-space:pre-wrap">' // etc.
        + val
        + '</div>';
}
// ...
// Note: rowId is known at this point
var myData = $('#myGrid').jqGrid('getCell',rowId,'myData');
var myDataWrapper = mydata.createColumn('');
data = data.substr(myDataWrapper.length-6,data.length-myDataWrapper.length);
```

Of course, this will break if someone adds more complex tags. So I looked at the way `getCell` actually finds the data. Unfortunately, at present, it just searches for the name so the code is:

```
var n = -1;
val colModel = $('#myGrid').jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
for (var i in colModel) {
    if (colModel[i].name === 'myData') {
    n = parseInt(i)+1;
}
var myData = $('#'+rowId+' td:nth-child('+n+') div').text();
```

It seemed wrong to duplicate code in `getCell`, but there doesn't seem the be any other way to find the column number from the name (at least, I couldn't find it!). This also assumes that the data is wrapped in single `div`, as in the first version.

Looking at the generated html, I noticed that jqGrid actually tags the cell using `aria-describedby` (which I've never seen before). If this is guaranteed to always be there, then the above can be done using:

```
var myData = $('#'+rowId+' td:[aria-describedby=myGrid_myData] div').text();
```

But this still uses the assumption that the data is wrapped in a single `div` and, of course, a future version of jqGrid could change or remove this attribute.

So I then tried the simple solution adding an id by wrapping the data in a `span` so I could easily find it:

```
createColumn: function (val, options) {
    return '<div style="white-space:pre-wrap">' // etc.
        + '<span id="' + options.gid + '_' + options.rowId + '_' + options.colModel.name + '">' + val + '</span>'
        + '</div>';
}
// ...
var myData = $('#myGrid_'+rowId+'_MyData').text();
```

This would seem to be the best way (as I have full control over it) but is there a better way to get the data that was originally passed to the formatter function which won't break on possible future upgrades to jqGrid and doesn't require adding extra tags?

Comment: It's very important to know **when** you need get the data from the cell and **in which context** (inside of custom formatter, callback, event handler and so on) you need to do this. For example if the row is *editing* with respect of inline or cell editing mode then you can't access the data of editing cell (from `'myData'` column). It's important to know how you fill the data. Which `datatype` has the grid? Do you use `loadonce: true` option or not? It would be good if you post an example of the code which you use to create jqGrid.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the initial part of your question:

> Since a custom formatter is adding extra tags to the data, and simply using getCell returns all the tags as well...

The standard way to get the data back without the extra tags is to implement an `unformat` function. From the jqGrid docs:

> As mentioned in Predefined Formatter chapter all predefined types are compatible with the editing modules. This means that the numbers, links, e-mails, etc., are converted so that they can be edited correctly. Also the methods (like getRowData and getCell) that get data, used this unformat in order to get the original value. The question is: What to do if we use a custom formatter function and want to to have the original value back if we use editing or methods getRowData and getCell?
>
> The answer is: You can use your own custom unformatter function to do that. This function can be used in colModel

For example:

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
...
   colModel: [ 
      ... 
      {name:'price', index:'price', width:60, align:"center", editable: true,
       formatter:imageFormat, 
       unformat:imageUnFormat},
      ...
   ]
...
});

function imageFormat( cellvalue, options, rowObject ){
    return '<img src="'+cellvalue+'" />';
}

function imageUnFormat( cellvalue, options, cell){
    return $('img', cell).attr('src');
}
```

See the [Unformatting](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter#unformatting) section of the jqGrid documentation for full details, including parameter descriptions.